# What operator is used when Rubik's cube is modeled as a group?

Tags: group-theory

When I earned about groups, a group was taken to be a set of elements that operated on each other to produce another member of the set, along with the properties of closure, unit element, inverse and associativity.

I have seen a different definition used for Rubik's cube.  By this definition, a group is formed by a set of generators whose combinations generate the rest of the group with appropriate restrictions for identity, inverse and associativity.  For the Rubik's cube, the generators are the 6 face rotations.

How can these two definitions be reconciled? In particular, what is the operator for the second definition?  It seems that the only way to determine if two elements (generator sequences) are identical, would be to check that each of the little cubies on the cube ended up in the same spot.  How does this get incorporated into the group definition?

Comment: This is a good question, and a good answer will explain how it relates to the concept of a [presentation of a group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group).

Answer (score 6):

The operator in the second representation is concatenation of “generator sequences” as you call them. The way you show that one sequence equals another is to use relations among the sequences. For instance, any face rotation to the fourth power equals the identity.

Comment: Might it make sense to talk about a group action on the cube coloring?

Comment: @user1153980 Since elements of the group correspond to orientations of the cube, this action is exactly the action of the group on itself by multiplication.

Comment: @AlexElzenaar we're not talking about rotations of a cube, we're talking about the Rubik's cube. Elements of the group correspond to what puzzle fans call "algorithms", or sequences of rotations of the cube's faces, but modded out by an equivalence relation. It's not simple.

Comment: @user1153980 yes, it absolutely does make sense to talk about that - that group action is what really matters to you if you want to solve the cube.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the colors and instead labeling each face independently we can interpret the action as a subgroup of a [permutation group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_group) with the operation being function composition. Now color them. This will change the nature of the group but we can still interpret it as function composition.

Alternatively we can consider strings of moves with the operation being concatenation as we would with [free groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_group). This approach is common when given generators and relations as you might with the Rubix cube group. For example all of the generating moves $g$ you mentioned we have $g^4=1$ which gives us a rule to help us reduce the strings. This is the same idea as when we define the dihedral group as an action on a regular polygon.